# Delete String(s) Between Two Pattern Matches

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I am trying to delete "PK WND 16026/1736" from the below text by removing any text between "RMK A02" and "SLP."

**Text**

```
KDFW 151753Z 17018G25KT 10SM FEW035 FEW120 SCT250 32/21 A2983 RMK AO2 PK WND 16026/1736 SLP093 T03220211 10322 20239 58008
```

**Code**

```
sed -e 's/\(RMK A02\).*\(SLP\)/\1\2/'
```

The above code doesn't appear to be working/deleting "PK WND 16026/1736."

Comment: You have `O` letter in the string, but a zero `0` in the pattern. `sed -e 's/\(RMK AO2\).*\(SLP\)/\1\2/'` should work.

Comment: Sharp eye, thank you! Sometimes it's hard to tell a 0 from a O, especially in coding font!

Comment: Can you please reply with an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: There are a couple of good coding fonts around which makes it easier to distinguish `0` and `O`, dito for `l` and `1`.  Have a look at [Inconsolata](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inconsolata) which can be found on most linux distro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
awk -F"RMK AO2.*SLP" '{$0=$0~FS?$1"RMK AO2 SLP "$2:$0}1' file
KDFW 151753Z 17018G25KT 10SM FEW035 FEW120 SCT250 32/21 A2983 RMK AO2 SLP 093 T03220211 10322 20239 58008
```